# Any virtual pc software that can use a physical partition as virtual hard drive?

Tags: virtualization, virtualenv, virtual-machine, virtualhost, vmware-server

I need to know if there is any pc-virtualization software for windows, that is able to use a physical partition or drive for a virtual machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware Workstation is the leading product in this market http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/overview.html

Comment: so, if i install vmware can i use a physical drive or parition for a virtual pc? Is that for sure?